# Writing to byte range within a file in Go

Tags: file, http, go, writefile

I am downloading a large file in concurrent Chunks of 10MB using GO as shown below.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    chunkSize := 1024 * 1024 * 10 // 10MB
    url := "http://path/to/large/zip/file/zipfile.zip"
    filepath := "zipfile.zip"
    res, _ := http.Head(url)
    maps := res.Header
    length, _ := strconv.Atoi(maps["Content-Length"][0]) // Get the content length from the header request

    // startByte and endByte determines the positions of the chunk that should be downloaded
    var startByte = 0
    var endByte = chunkSize - 1

    for startByte < length {
        if endByte > length {
            endByte = length - 1
        }
        go func(startByte, endByte int) {
            client := &http.Client {}
            req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)

            rangeHeader := fmt.Sprintf("bytes=%d-%d", startByte, endByte)
            req.Header.Add("Range", rangeHeader)
            resp,_ := client.Do(req)
            defer resp.Body.Close()

            data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
            addToFile(filepath, startByte, endByte, data)
        }(startByte, endByte)

        startByte = endByte + 1
        endByte += chunkSize
    }
}

func addToFile(filepath string, startByte, endByte int, data []byte) {
    // TODO: write to byte range in file
}
```

How should I go about creating the file, and writing to a specified byte range within the file corresponding to the byte range of the chunk?

For example, if I get the data from the bytes 262144000-272629759, the addToFile function should write to 262144000-272629759 within the zipfile.zip. Then, if data from another range is obtained, that should be written to the respective range in zipfile.zip.

Comment: Aside: the bound check should be `endByte >= length`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to do this. Change the addToFile function as shown below.

```
func addToFile(filepath string, startByte int, data []byte) {
    f, err := os.OpenFile(filepath, os.O_CREATE | os.O_WRONLY, os.ModeAppend)
    if err != nil {
        panic("File not found")
    }
    whence := io.SeekStart
    _, err = f.Seek(int64(startByte), whence)
    f.Write(data)
    f.Sync() //flush to disk
    f.Close()
}
```